# Definition numbering colon

Tags: latexmk

I have a problem with theorem numbering colon in LaTeX. I can make it dot after definition like this
Definition 1.1.
 I want to write definition like this 
Definition 1.1:
 Help me.

Comment: Could you post a minimal compilable code?

Comment: In particular, do please tell us whether you use a package such as `amsthm` or `ntheorem` to help create theorem-like environments.

Comment: I use a package such as  amsthm

Comment: Thank you. I do it.

Comment: Why is this tagged latexmk? Latexmk does not seem to be related to this at all